# Implementing advanced search in sharepoint 2007 wss

Tags: sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

These days I have been developing a sharepoint site where I have implemented some custom web parts, and now I need a advanced search feature where I can search wikis, forums, blogs, document libraries, etc...

I heard that there exists a rich advanced search web part in MOSS 2007, is there a similar web part in WSS 3.0(which I couldn't find until now...) or is there a third party web part that can cater my requirements of searching?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

WSS 3.0 Does not support functionality of advance search. If you wish to use to use advance search facility i would suggest you to install search server which is again free of cost

Comment: sorry, I am not familiar with search server, can you give me an overview and can you tell me how to integrate search server to sharepoint 2007 (wss3.0) to do advanced search features?

Comment: Well, I have looked at search server 2008 express articles. They all state that search server runs great and how to configure it on MOSS but not in WSS3.0, can you give me a better article that describes installing and configuring search server 2008 express n wss 3.0 but not in MOSS?

Comment: sorry for delayed reply you would have to basically upgrade wss 3.0 to search server 2008 follow the below article from technet http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297193(office.12).aspx